# How to suspend small cabinet from ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, hanging, chain

I want to put my NAS in a small cabinet. I do not want to hang the cabinet to the wall, for a few reasons : there's no stud where I want it to go, the wall is plaster board, and toggle bolts require large holes. Since I'm renting, that would be too difficult to patch when I leave. Also, the plaster board would just amplify the noise

So I'm thinking of hanging it from the ceiling, which is reinforced concrete. I devise two ways for this. Which one do you think it's best?

First method : mobile with line/chain [image: Schema of cabinet hanging from two lines, both connected to a single eye screw]

Second method : fixed with threaded rod. Secured with nuts and washers (blue) on top and bottom.
[image: Schema of cabinet with a threaded rod through it and the ceiling]

Note that both are using only 1 hole in the ceiling, because I want it to be minimally invasive.

For that, I'm considering using this type of bolt : https://www.hornbach.ch/de/p/messing-spreizduebel-msd-m10-34-25-stueck/8229615

(is it called brass anchor?)

I'd get the M6 size, or even smaller if I can find. Because the total weight to hang is 5 kg / 11 pounds. Might go up to 10kg/22lbs if I add some more drives in the future.

So, what do you think? I'd any if these preferred? Or any other suggestions?

Thank you!

---

Edit : I'm attaching a photo of the wall to illustrate why I'm reluctant to pierce it. It has this extra layer on top of the boards, about 2cm thick) and with non uniform look. So holes will be very very visible even after patching, since you cannot sand it

[image: Photo of the wall]

Comment: What is an NAS?

Comment: 1. Do you have permission from the landlord to drill and mount hardware in the concrete ceiling? 2. FWIW, though I'm no expert, I'd say patching a hole in concrete is possibly harder than patching a hole in a plaster wall. 3. Since noise is an issue, the NAS may vibrate a dangling cabinet and make audible noise, too. A thick cloth pad under the NAS may dampen noise in a fixed-to-wall or on-floor cabinet quite well. My server sits on pot holders. 4. A dangling cabinet means loose power and network cables flexing constantly.

Comment: @RMDman Network Attached Storage.  Basically a hard drive(s) in a box that you can connect to your network for remote storage, often for backup purposes.

Comment: Something light wouldn’t require a stud for a successful wall mount. 4 plugs around 5mm would be adequate and I’m sure you can find rubber isolators for the vibration concern.

Comment: And in my opinion, a single m6 anchor in the ceiling (the worst/weakest application) would be a poor choice for something you really don’t want to fall.

Comment: @Triplefault it did not occur to me to ask specifically about the ceiling. Usually much is allowed as long as you restore it when you leave. 2. Why more difficult? The compound, yes, but the hole is much smaller. Also, these plasterboards have a 2cm layer of  plaster on top of the board. 3. True, didn't want to use floor space. 4. True, thanks! So my 2nd proposition is better, as it's hanging but not dangling?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate why do you say the ceiling is the weakest application? It's concrete, so m6 is [rated for 65 kg](https://fiproductmedia.azureedge.net/media/Load%20Tables/Load%20Tables%20fischer/LT_MS_07_21_FR.pdf)

Comment: Thank you all for valuable comments! I've added a photo of the hollow wall to illustrate why I'm reluctant to pierce it.

Comment: Patching that wall would be difficult to get it to look correct afterward, true. My NAS is on the floor, so it can't fall if a ceiling anchor pulls out. The long bolt won't have flexibility and may bend/break if run into. Try using old concrete pieces to practice with a hammer drill for mounting the inserts. And hope you don't hit rebar when drilling into the ceiling, Could the NAS fit nicely on an existing bookcase or under a piece of furniture?

Comment: It’s not clear to me if your strength link refers to shear (sideways) or tensile (pull straight out) strength. https://www.fixfast.com/skills-hub/what-is-the-difference-between-shear-and-tensile-strength-of-a-fastener

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate sorry, it's in French. it says "in traction", so I'm 80% sure it's tensile, not shear. But yes, not very clear.

Comment: @Triplefault On the floor it risks restricts the opening of the door - not much, but a bit. It's the fallback option, indeed.

Why hope to not hit rebar? Probably won't since required hole depth is 25mm, which is where rebar would start. But still curious why.

Comment: Just to add one more crazy idea, how about a pole (that might have hooks for coats or hats) pushing the cabinet against the ceiling? You could have rubber buffers for sound attenuation. No holes to patch...

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă "Why hope to not hit rebar?" You'd need a hammer drill and concrete drill bit to make the hole. These won't drill through the steel rebar. On another tack, I would not trust a small anchor for overhead items, The concrete could be old, prone to crack at the surface, and a small anchor might not be held firmly enough, especially after side forces from knocking things against the hanging cabinet. A larger, deeper anchor might be a better direction, then the rebar question comes into play.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I love this idea ! I think I'll try this first ! Thanks

Comment: @Triplefault Thanks for the clarification ! Yes, rebar would require some REAL power tools, not the small hammer drill I have. Great point about concrete cracking, I didn't think of it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use wall anchors, i would probably get two boards, maybe 1x3, 16" long each and screw them into the studs. Then attach your small cabinet to the two boards.
I did something like that when I need a strong attachment and didn't trust wall anchors to do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! Indeed, that is a solution, and I've done it for the TV. Unfortunately over here in Switzerland [the studs are made of metal](https://file2.okorder.com/attach/2019/09/25/e7a8fa7c3bd31c653c41ad3c5bc5ef9b.jpg), so not sure I can simply screw into them.

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă How to mount to metal studs would be a really good new question, and may already have been answered.